# Python Program that takes an integer and returns a list of n even integers

Tags: python, range

Question: Write a program which first defines a function evens(n). The function should take an integer as the argument and return a list of n even integers starting with 2 using the range function which takes a third argument that is the "step". Rewrite the function using the third argument in the range.

What I have so far:

```
def evens(n):
    evensLst = []

    for i in range(1,n+1):
            evensLst.append(2*i)
    return evensLst 

    for i in range(1,n+1):
            evensLst.append(3*i)
    return evensLst 

n = raw_input("Enter an integer: ") 
print "Evens: ", evens(n)
```

Comment: That doesn't come even close to fulfilling the requirements.

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Comment: I'm totally lost. I used an example from our textbook to get where I am now, and apparently I'm lost because I'm not even close to answering the problems. I guess my actual question is: How do I write a function to use the third argument in the range?

Comment: Not the third argument "in the range"; the third argument **accepted by the `range` function**. To understand how that works, start by looking at the documentation: `help(range)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def evens(n):
    return [2*n for n in range(1, n+1)]
```

If you use the "third" argument of range, you get the list you are looking for directly.

```
def evens(n):
    return range(2, 2*n+1, 2)
```

Comment: @user1210588 : Both of these functions return the list of n even numbers, but only the second satisfies the constraint of using the third argument of range(). Try both of them and you'll see what that final 2 does.

Comment: be the cool kid in school and use a `lambda`. `evens = lambda n: [ n for n in xrange(1, n + 1, 2 )]`